# How to solve Sequence ordering using MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

if my mapper emits (key, value) pairs such as:

- (A, B) implying A results in B
- (B, C) implying B results in C
- (C, D) implying C results in D
- etc

I want my reducer to emit as follows

- (A, B -> C -> D) meaning A will result in B, B will result in C, C will result in D
- (B, C -> D) meaning B will result in C, C will result in D
- etc

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend looking into https://spark.apache.org/.

Comment: Specifically, look at Spark Graphframes